# Вопросы о языках программирования

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

Некоторое время назад был задан [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/442005/178988) о том, являются ли языки разметки языками программирования. Он собрал охапку минусов (только я поставил этому вопросу плюс), был закрыт и был удалён [Духом сообщества ♦](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0).

Сейчас обнаружил такой же по смыслу [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13665671/4928642) на английском SO, где он замечательно живёт с рейтингом +5 (для просмотра числа голосов там у меня рейтинга не хватает).

В чём причина? Первый вопрос чем-то хуже? Или здесь отношение к тематике другое?

Comment: Вопрос довольно-таки субъективный, но на него можно дать обоснованные, конструктивные ответы. Думаю, с должной модерацией ответов такой вопрос задавать можно. Кстати, тот вопрос на En.SO имеет +5-0. Проголосовал за восстановление вопроса.

Comment: Говорят что связка HTML+CSS Тьюринг-полна, но я не углублялся в доказательство. С практической точки зрения @Etki прав, но его почему-то заминусовали.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, HTML относится к декларативным языкам программирования. Если привести определения и примеры, получится вполне конструктивный и обоснованный ответ.

Comment: [Вот клеточный автомат со 110 правилом на HTML+CSS3](https://github.com/elitheeli/stupid-machines/blob/master/rule110/rule110-full.html).А вот [доказательство полноты самого автомата](http://www.complex-systems.com/pdf/15-1-1.pdf). Короче технически являются, но на практике так никто делать не будет.

Comment: Вопрос хуже - в нем три пункта, и если первый еще как-то тянет на нормальный, то "Можно ли назвать скриптерами тех, кто программирует на PHP? Или кто вообще такие скриптери" - совсем нет.

Comment: Ну если его отредактировать в "Является ли связка HTML+CSS Тьюринг-полной?" и в ответ привести пример с клеточным автоматом и некоторые идеи из доказательства, то он будет нормальным. Но что-то я сильно сомневаюсь что юзер сам понимает про что спрашивает и в какую на самом деле глубь математики закапывает его с виду простой вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос на SO по ссылке стоило бы перенести на Programmers.SE, но он слишком стар для этого.

Comment: @igumnov тогда его надо сначала отредактировать, а потом уже открыть. а сейчас на этом треше висит 3 голоса за открытие, хотя вопрос как был ни о чем, так и остался

Comment: @PashaPash, вопрос как вопрос. Да, не шедевр. Да, автор много чего не знает, вот и спрашивает. Что мешает просто ответить (кто во что горазд) и забыть о нем? Кстати, это далеко не первый (на ХК) вопрос о том, является ли html языком программирования. И тут нет ничего страшного, что 3 из 10 говорят -- "ДА", а остальные -- "НЕТ". Поскольку 5 из них приводят какие-то (видимо все же разумные) аргументы, то пусть ТС дальше сам думает право ли тут большинство...

Comment: @avp кроме вопроса о том, ЯП ли HTML, это еще и вопрос о "скриптерах" и "является ли программированием". если бы там был только вопрос про HTML - я бы на него сам ответил. Если это не первый вопрос - то нужно закрыть как дубликат. Не вижу проблемы - или "нормальный вопрос - нормальный ответ" иди "треш про скриптеров - закрытие и удаление".

Comment: @PashaPash, да там 3 вопроса в одном, что тоже не приветсвуется. Если Вы (и 4 остальных) такой формалист, то и закрывать надо с формулировкой -- "неправильный формат вопроса, ...". Мне кажется, что в данном случае (и в большинстве других) это все мелкие придирки, в общем, неправильно. А с дубликатами -- если не лень этим заниматься, то, как говориться,  флаг в руки (только сгоряча дров не наломайте).

Comment: @avp Сейчас на вопросе 3 голоса за переоткрытие. Ни один из этих 3-х ни пальцем не пошевелил чтобы привести вопрос в нормальный вид.  Предложите флаг им. Меня этот вопрос в его текущем состоянии (закрытый/удаленный) вполне устраивает. Особенно с учетом того, что ни с одним из ответов я не согласен.

Comment: @PashaPash, меня тоже (в смысле переоткрытый), не вижу смысла что-то в нем редактировать (видимо, также считают и остальные, голосовавшие за переоткрытие).

Comment: @PashaPash, я ещё до закрытия ему заголовок отредактировал. Сам вопрос вполне нормально выглядит, на мой взгляд. А когда не согласен ни с одним ответом, надо взять и написать свой ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy особенно нормально выглядит часть про скриптеров?

Comment: @PashaPash, ну да, кусок про скриптеров - это далеко не лучшая часть вопроса, но не не могу сказать, что он меня раздражает. Лично я не вижу причин удалять этот кусок, но если кому-то хочется, то это его право. Однако, что-то этого желающего до сих пор не нашлось.

Comment: @Qwertiy желающего не нашлось не потому, что лень. а потому, что это хоть и улучшит вопрос, но явно противоречит намерениям автора - он хотел узнать, скриптер он или нет, а кто-то возьмет и решит за него, что он больше не хочет знать.

Answer (score 1):

**Заминусован и закрыт вполне заслуженно.**

В нем три пункта, и если первый еще как-то тянет на нормальный, то "Можно ли назвать скриптерами тех, кто программирует на PHP? Или кто вообще такие скриптери" - совсем нет.

Ну если его отредактировать в "Является ли связка HTML+CSS Тьюринг-полной?" и в ответ привести пример с клеточным автоматом и некоторые идеи из доказательства, то он будет нормальным. Но что-то я сильно сомневаюсь что юзер сам понимает про что спрашивает и в какую на самом деле глубь математики закапывает его с виду простой вопрос